# writing in a file using structures

Tags: c, file, structure

I wrote a code that is supposed to write into a file but when i execute the program it says "error in saving student data".Here is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct Student{
 int numberOfStudents;
 char name; // onoma foithth
 char surname; // epi8eto foithth


};


int main(){
    struct Student  s1; 
    FILE *file=fopen("d:\\student.txt","w");
    if(file==NULL){
        printf("error in saving student data");
        return 1;
    }
    while(1){

    printf("Enter number of students: ");
    scanf("%d",&s1.numberOfStudents);
    printf("enter name: ");
    scanf("%s",&s1.name);
    printf("enter surname: ");
    scanf("%s",&s1.surname);

    fprintf(file,"%d\t%s\t%s\n",s1.numberOfStudents,s1.name,s1.surname);
    printf("continue (Y/N)");
    char ch=getch();
    if (ch=='N' || ch=='n')
    break;
    }


    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I have searched but i can't find the problem.where is my mistake?

Comment: `char name;` -> You do realise this is just one character so - `scanf("%s",&s1.name);` will not work!

Comment: File "d:\student.txt" cannot be opened for writing.  Perhaps another program, like an editor owns it.

Comment: Are you sure you have write access to that directory? AFAIK root directory in volumes usually aren't directly writable - you need Admin.

Comment: @iBug I have never had problems writing to the root directory of a USB drive.

Comment: Forget writing to file for the time being, but how are you planning to use a single character for storing a name? From the format specifier you used, it is clear your intentions are pretty clear though, that is to use char array for both first and surnames

Comment: so what i should do?

Comment: I would read a book and look into arrays. Then read the manual page for `scanf`. Afterwards get use to the debugger. But first check that you can write to the appropriate directory

Comment: @Code-Apprentice For USB drive, that's always fine because they mostly use FAT32, which does not have permission control. In practice `D:` is often a builtin volume with NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

`name` field of structure should be `char array` if you want to store `onoma foithth` in that as shown. modify your structure as

```
typedef struct Student{
 int numberOfStudents;
 char name[10]; // onoma foithth
 char surname; // epi8eto foithth


};
```

and then while scanning `name` remove `&` because `name` is itself address.

```
scanf("%s",s1.name);
```

Make sure you gave correct path in `fopen()`

Comment: There are no strings in `C`. They simply have array of characters which when null-terminated, could be called a string.

Comment: @sjsam The C standard library defines  "A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character.".  Perhaps C does not have a _string_ as another language defines it, but this is a C question.

Comment: Agree that In `C` there is no `string` data type like in `c++` but In `C` can't I say `char array` as a `string` and vice versa ?

Comment: @chux : Aha. Perhaps the first sentence I wrote is a bit misleading. I should've written that as `C doesn't define string as a type`. But the point was pretty much clear.

Comment: @raja [re](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239678/writing-in-a-file-using-structures/48239751?noredirect=1#comment83461862_48239751) A _string_ can be an _array_ or part of it.   A _character array_ may be a _string_ or not - depending on its contents.  `char a[2] = { 'b', 'c' };`  --> `a` is a `char` array, yet not a _string_.